# Counting apartments in spherical buildings

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups

Is there a formula for the number of apartments in a finite, spherical building? 
To be specific, is there a formula that depends on the associated Coxeter group and the thickness of the building?

Thanks!

Comment: At first I thought this was a real world problem.

Comment: Maybe it has applications :-).

Comment: If I remember correctly, every thick finite building comes from a finite group G which admits a BN-pair structure. Then the number you are interested in is $|G:N|=|G|/|N|$. I do not know however, if the orders of $G$ and $N$ are expressible in terms of thickness and the root system (I think, it is possible, but I do not know enough about finite groups). I am adding the tag "finite groups" and removing "algebraic topology" (since the former is relevant and the latter is not).